# How to get Gmail new message notifications without having to sync?

Tags: sync, notifications, gmail

How can I get Gmail new message notifications without having to sync an account with my Android phone?

I thought there may be a way by either :

1. going through XMPP somehow
2. configuring Gmail to notify Google+ when I get a new email and then I would get a G+ notification which would be fine.

I just want my phone to tell me "you have a new email" without having to actually sync anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without having to sync"? Gmail already uses push (via *Google Cloud Messaging*) to deliver new mails to your device, so it has no more overhead than the G+ solution you're thinking of.

Comment: I want to be notified that I have a new email without having to sync my gmail account with android. Yes Gmail does this but it requires syncing your account which totally destroys the whole point. The whole point of getting a push notification is to save your battery and data not having to PULL/SYNC every 5 minutes.

Comment: It doesn't pull every 5 minutes. It runs when it gets a push message, to download exactly the new mail it's just been told about. It's the most efficient way to see your mail.

Comment: I want a push notification without syncing. That's what I'm asking for. I want to get as many of those services in my settings, stopped as possible. I know how much data and battery all those services are using and gmail is a big one. I just want push without sync

Comment: The closest thing I've found is zappier.com and it's a paid service :(

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging, which GMail and most other Google apps use for push notification, runs on the Google Talk infrastructure, which is XMPP already. Can you explain which part of sync you don't like? I thin kwe're getting confused by the fact that your definitions of push and sync seem to be different than ours.

Comment: @GAThrawn, i don't like that syncing pulls data at set intervals when i do not necessarily want that data stored on my phone nor do i want to spend the battery life or data on pulling that unwanted information to my phone. Just send me a popup telling me the email is there and I'll download it if i want it or check it on my home desktop if i want to. I don't want my phone syncing with google however many times a day

Comment: I don't think i can explain it any better. I want to get a notification that i have a new email and at the very same time i do not want to have my email sync or stored on my device at all.

Comment: @Joshua, so why not just go into GMail options and turn off "Sync Gmail" while leaving "Notifications" on?

Comment: @GAThrawn that is not working. That is exactly what i have done. But i have foind an answer. There is an app called IM+ which is a jabber client that has something called push mode. It does exactly what I want from a quick test. I'll do a bit more testing and possibly offer it as the answer.

Comment: Turning on sync in the settings **doesn't necessarily** poll for updates at set intervals. For some apps it will, some (like Gmail) it won't.

Comment: @Dan, not sure which gmail app you're using but mine gives me the option of syncing either all or the last 30 messages or nothing. And it turns off push automatically when you turn off sync.

Comment: What's that got to do with whether it uses polling or push? All it affects is the initial sync when you first add the account, and when it deletes locally cached messages.

Comment: Push does not work without sync and sync automatically pulls the newest 30 emails to my phone which i do not want.

Comment: More and more i am becoming frustrated with ALL the apps that require sync in order to give you push. Why are they mutually exclusive? They are completely different processes. Push uses the server resources to give you a simple notification when you have a new email.  This requires LITTLE strain on your battery and dada plan and CPU. BUT syncing requires MORE strain on the user's CPU and involves pulling data from the servers and running cycles to check what data has been downloaded and what needs to change etc. Twitter also requires that you check on sync in order to get notifications. So ann

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a (mostly) non-Android solution for you.

You'll need to (sign up for and) use [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com).

Create a recipe.<sup>1</sup>

Your **This** will be the [Gmail channel](https://ifttt.com/gmail), specifically the [Any new email](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/triggers/185-any-new-email) trigger.<sup>2</sup>

Your **That** will be however you'd like to be notified. I like [Pushover](https://ifttt.com/pushover) but [SMS](https://ifttt.com/sms) will work just as well. You'll use the [Send me an SMS](https://ifttt.com/channels/sms/actions/3-send-me-an-sms) action (or [send a notification](https://ifttt.com/channels/pushover/actions/75-send-a-notification) for Pushover).<sup>3</sup>

Now you can be notified of new messages in your Gmail without even actually having Gmail on your phone.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> If you prefer, you can just use [this recipe (SMS)](https://ifttt.com/recipes/150020-send-sms-when-gmail-arrives) or [this recipe (Pushover)](https://ifttt.com/recipes/150086-send-pushover-notification-for-new-gmail).

<sup>2</sup> If you don't want to be notified on *every* new message, there are other triggers you can use, like "New email from" or "New email from search" that can be more specific.

<sup>3</sup> Unfortunately there is no Google+ channel. There a lots of other channels for lots of other services.

<sup>4</sup> IFTTT triggers usually don't go off more than every fifteen minutes, so don't expect your notification to be instantaneous.

Comment: I have to say. I am very very thankful for this solution. I had no idea about this free service until now. It looks amazing. I'll check it out and get back to you for the answer. Thank you @Al E.

Comment: Ifttt by the way can only currently push ONE email account.

Comment: @Joshua: yes, unfortunately you are currently limited to a single email account. They've also recently added the [Pushbullet](https://ifttt.com/pushbullet) channel if you're looking for a different alert mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I gave the answer to Al E. For taking the time to help me and provide a great working solution. ( though not the solution I ended up going with as 1)  I didn't want to fork over $5 for the pushover app or 2) I'd already implemented another solution that works great as well.

THE SOLUTION I WENT WITH WAS THIS

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite

The app is called IM+
It's free to use and install with ads.

Set it up with your email accounts and go into settings and switch on "Google push mode" in "push settings"

Turn off or even disable the gmail app and voila -- gmail push settings without syncing. The great thing about the  XMPP Network is, there are a lot of other services you can get push notifications for for free.

Thanks to everyone who helped out with this.